# Yii not showing errorSummary

Tags: php, file-upload, yii, validation

My Yii code not showing error summery before save movie in database.. what's the problem ?

Form code: http://jsfiddle.net/SRMzc/

**it's actionCreate function:**

```
  public function actionCreateM()
    {
        $model=new Movie;

        if(isset($_POST['Movie']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Movie'];

            $photos = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('photo');

            if (isset($_POST['Movie']['youtube_id'])){
                $model->youtube_id=$_POST['Movie']['youtube_id'];
            }



            if (isset($_POST['Movie']['poster_uri'])){
                $file=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'poster_uri');
                if(isset($file)){
                    $model->poster_uri = $model->short_title .'_poster.' . $file->extensionName;
                }
            }

            if($model->save()).......
```

**Rules:**

from movie model

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('title, short_title, year, imdb_rate, rate, cast, director, summary, release_date, duration, views, featured', 'required'),
        array('views, featured, available_status', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('title, short_title, genre, director', 'length', 'max'=>64),
        array('poster_uri', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty' => true),
        array('cast', 'length', 'max'=>256),
        array('year', 'length', 'max'=>4),
        array('lang', 'length', 'max'=>2),
        array('imdb_rate', 'length', 'max'=>3),
        array('rate', 'length', 'max'=>5),
        array('duration', 'length', 'max'=>11),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('title, short_title, views, featured, available_status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}
```

Comment: You have a `die()` in the middle of the code, is that on purpose?

Comment: sorry.. removed.. still not showing error summary

Comment: Where do you call validate and what are your rules? Where do you print errorSummary() ?

Comment: You would print your error summary form your view. Please show that. Your rules would be in your Movie model. Please show that too.

Comment: hi all, I have add rules form movie model.. and form code: http://jsfiddle.net/SRMzc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error summary works with ajax. you need to set enableAjaxValidation to true in your form definition. then you need to track that ajax call in action and validate your model and then echo the errors (check create action in Yii blog demo app for more details).

If you need to validate the code in PHP try following

```
if(!$model->save())
{
    print_r($model->getErrors());
}
```

or

```
if(!$model->validate())
{
    print_r($model->getErrors());
}
else 
{
    $model->save();
}
```

validation code goes something like this

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='comment-form')
{
    echo CActiveForm::validate($comment);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Edit:- You don't really need to enable ajax to get validation summary. you can have php code for the same, something like this.

```
if($model->validate())
{
    $model->save();
    //render some other view here
}
$this->render('Your_update_or_create_view');
```

Comment: @Uday `errorSummary` doesn't absolutely need ajaxvalidation(so please correct that). however i agree with your method of showing errorSummary for ajax. @AnasA i think you might have missed something in your `if` statements which prevents the model with error being passed to the view. so if you add your entire actionCreateM , we could help you correct that.

Comment: @bool.dev Yes I agree with you, the action does not need to be an ajax call to return validation errors. but the code shown above makes active validation using ajax calls, like for onFocusLost event of a textbox field.

Comment: well, the line(s) "Error summary works with ajax. you need to set enableAjaxValidation to true in your form definition." is misleading, when the question reads "errorSummary not showing". if you intended to give an alternate solution, its ok, but wouldn't it be better to mention that? i'm just saying that he never asked for active validation, but if you are offering that, you could have mentioned it, which will (IMHO) make your answer unambiguous. [ps: ignore my previous comment, which i'll be deleting shortly]

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be **$model->errorSummary()** while you are using

```
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

Comment: `$form->errorSummary($model);` is correct check the errorSummary documentation, the method doesn't belong to any model object but belongs to CHtml class, and CActiveForm class also has a separate implementation